# What’s the reason for closing the Community Promotion Ads posted for the previous years?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Many of Community Promotion Ads posts created in the past years have been closed as duplicates.

Why is this done?
Does closing the Community Promotion Ads posts as duplicate help the search engines to show the more recent ones?

Comment: The year's over that's why. The same happens to the Winter Bash posts I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s simply that they get reset each year.  From [Community Promotion Ads — 2019](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3749/835)

> ## Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

Closing just ensures that people add new ads to the right post for the year.